# JavaScript not running with Perl CGI

Tags: javascript, apache, perl, cgi

Inside the cgi-bin folder, I have an experiment.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
require "../common/config.pl";

print header;
print start_html(-title=>"Add Assignment");


print<<EOT;
  <script type = "application/javascript" src = "experiment.js"></script>
EOT

print h2("Add New Automated Assignment");

# print<<AEOT;
#   <script>experiment();</script>
# AEOT
print end_html;
```

In the same folder I have experiment.js

```
function experiment(){
    alert('ghello world');
}
```

However there is problem with the experiment.js file inclusion. In the log files I get the following error:

```
End of script output before headers: experiment.js
```

I searched for this error and found it was relate to cgi files. So my guess is that apache2 is interpreting experiment.js as a cgi file. Am I right in this? If yes, what is the proper way to set it up so that JavaScript and cgi could be used together?

Comment: *Warning*: The use of CGI.pm is [not recommended](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE), it has been removed from Perl Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I searched for this error and found it was relate to cgi files. So my guess is that apache2 is interpreting experiment.js as a cgi file. I am right in this?

Yes

> If yes, what is the proper way to setup so that javascript and cgi could be used together.

Don't put non-CGI programs in your `cgi-bin`. Put them with the rest of your static files.

You'll need to adjust the URL. `src="/js/experiment.js"` for example.